# find command in Linux to identify any file (not directory) modified in the last day, and not owned by root

Tags: linux, find

So far I am trying :

```
find / -mtime -1 -print ! -user root
```

However it doesn't seem to work. Any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to constraint your search to file entries you must add the parameter `-type`

Should be something like this:

`find / -mtime -1 -print ! -user root -type f`

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason this still returns directories